# c# An ImageButton that is dynamically created in a databound ListView doesn't post back

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, postback, imagebutton

I'm fairly sure I know why this occurs, essentially that the control is creating dynamically too late in the page lifecycle for the event wireup system to see it, but I'm not realy sure what to do about it:

I've a ListView that is displaying forum posts for my custom forum. Some posts have attachments. The attachemnts are rendered during the ItemDataBound event: the Item's content is searched for an asp PlaceHolder and an ImageButton is dynamically created and added to the placeholder:

```
      ImageButton ib_Delete = new ImageButton();
      ib_Delete.ID = "ib_DeleteAttachment_" + myfile.Id.ToString();
      ib_Delete.ImageUrl = "~/images/icons/delete.png";
      ib_Delete.Width = 16;
      ib_Delete.Height = 16;
      ib_Delete.CssClass = "attachmentDeleteButton";
      ib_Delete.OnClientClick = "return ConfirmDeleteAttachment();";
      ib_Delete.CommandArgument = mf.Id.ToString() + '@' + m.Id;
      ib_Delete.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(DeleteMessageAttachment_Click);
      myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ib_Delete);
```

Now, the DeleteMessageAttachment_Click method in the .cs never fires, and indeed the javascript onclick looks like:

> onclick="return ConfirmDeleteAttachment();"

I actually copied the ImageButton creation code off another page in the same project, one that *doesnt* have the ImageButtons rendered in a databinding related event, and code for those on the client side looks like:

> onclick="return
>   ConfirmDeleteAttachment();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
>   WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ctl00$cphPage$MC2$ib_DeleteAttachment_12345",
>   "", true, "", "", false, false))"

..so I feel pretty sure that it's a problem because I'm creating my controls at the wrong point in the page lifecycle but question is how do I do it at the right time? Should I, in my Page_Load, precreate a load of ImageButtons and hold them in a class-wide Dictionary<> so I can pull them out at the right time? Would the event wireup system see them if I did this? Just not sure what people do to make sure stuff gets created at the right time so that it can be used at another time..

Thanks all

Comment: You have to recreate controls in page_init or page_load(at the latest) with the same ID as before. Why are you creating them dynamically at all? You could use another, nested web-databound control like `Repeater` for your `ImageButtons`s.

Comment: I'm creating them dynamically cos.. er.. that's how it is in the other page and I just took that code and put it into the ListViewItemDataBound event handler to render them onto the page. I'm struggling to imagine how I use a Repeater control in the manner you suggest though: if a question has 20 answers and each answer has between 2 and 5 attachments and the answers are rendered in a listview databinding event, won't the repeater only go and render them at the wrong time also? I'll go and look up how to use a repeater so I actually feel like I know a little of what I'm talking about.. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to nest the repeater and have it work with the datasource (MindScape Lightspeed) in a related fashion - I can find plenty of examples of DataSet/DataRelation and it's a paradigm I understand but LightSpeed is relatively new, as is maintaining this project.. Should I look to do the whole thing another way?